# Keeping a small item refrigerated in carry-on on short domestic flights

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, hand-luggage

My next trip is composed of two domestic flights with a short connection. I will be travelling with carry-on luggage only, containing cheese that is best kept a fridge temperature.

**What is the best solution to keep it refrigerated during the whole journey ?** Time from fridge to fridge is about 5h.

- My current fare does not include checked in luggage
- Ice packs may be allowed ([company website](http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/guidevoyageur/pratique/marchandises-interdites-airfrance.htm) does not list them in forbidden items), but I'd rather avoid freezing the cheese
- There is some leeway in the temperature, no need to keep it at a constant 3°C. Anything below 8-10°C should be ok.
- Cheese size is ~10x5x5 cm

---

**EPILOGUE**

*First trip* - Joe Blow was right, the cheese was denied boarding by security. Had it been sliced first it would have made it through.

*Second trip* - I wrapped two of those cheeses in a thermal bag, and checked the suitcase that contained them. While I had ample time at the connecting airport to board my second flight, the baggage did not. The last flight was late at night so the cheese spent the night at the airport, only to be delivered in the morning. It was still slightly cold (so was the night in early November) and perfectly edible.

Comment: What country?  Domestic or International?

Comment: Depending on the cheese, refrigeration may not be necessary at all. See for example http://askkaren.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/325/~/does-all-cheese-need-to-be-refrigerated%3F These are US guidelines. The rest of the world tends to be even more relaxed, e.g. most people in the Netherlands wouldn't bother with putting a Gouda in the fridge ever and it's not uncommon in France to see a desert cart with soft cheeses out in the open for many hours.

Comment: > I'd rather avoid freezing the cheese -- I do not have any solid data on this but I seriously doubt an ice pack or two the size of a travel cooler could freeze something.

Comment: Products which are designed to keep medication (such as insulin) cool while travelling might work for you. [Frio](http://www.frioinsulincoolingcase.com/), for example, doesn't use an ice pack, and is available globally via Amazon. It's a flat, envelope-type design and has sizes which would easily accommodate your cheese.

Comment: You could ask the flight crew if it is possible to put it in the cooler that they have; or on ice with them (depending on the size of the item of course). However, I have yet to find cheese that goes bad in room temperature; and the cabin is a few degrees cooler than room temperature on most flights.

Comment: You do not refrigerate cheese.   But wait - would a cheese that size make it through security??

Comment: I quite often drop an ice pack in my lunch box to keep it fresh. Never had frozen lunch :) it's usually quite cool, even after 4-5 hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is **not to worry about it**. Cheese was created because it keeps much better than fresh dairy products, and most (all?) hard cheeses and uncut soft cheeses will keep fine for *weeks* at room temperature.

But if you must, a solid ice pack wrapped in a towel and placed in a plastic bag with the cheese ought to do the trick.  Emphasis on the *solid* there: [TSA permits ice packs](http://blog.tsa.gov/2012/03/clarification-on-icepacks-and-empty.html) as long as they're completely frozen.